# (SQL) How to compare each row to all other rows in Presto

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I'm working with AWS Athena which uses Presto. Let's say I have a SQL table with columns A, B, C, and D. Assume table is sorted by column C, ascending.

I need to compare each row to all the other rows and check if current row's D value is the maximum value out of all rows whose C values are less than current row's C value. Then append a boolean value in column F. Code in Python would look something like:

```
D_val_list = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    max_val_D = df[:index]['D'].max() #Sorted on column C
    if row['D'] < max_val_D:
        D_val_list.append(FALSE)
    else:
        D_val_list.append(TRUE)
df['F'] = D_val_list
```

Using the provisional jupyter notebook in Athena times out (the dataset is millions of rows long) and I figure connecting to AWS via local jupyter instance would have similar issues.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you would use window functions -- something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when d < coalesce(max(d) over (order by c
                                            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) is null,
                               d + 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag          
from t;
```

This logic would work assuming that `c` is unique.  That said, there might be alternative depending on the exact nature of the data.

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I need. Unfortunately Athena times out when I try to run it all at once but if I add conditions to the subquery then it seems to be ok. Is it possible to limit the subquery to search the rows where A = current row's A?

Answer (score 0):

You have to discretely order your rows on `c` in Athena because of its distributed nature. You can use window functions on top of the ordered set to achieve your desired results:

```
SELECT 
     a,
     b,
     c,
     d,   
     CASE WHEN d>lag(max_so_far) OVER () THEN true ELSE false END as f
FROM (
    SELECT a,
        b,
        c,
        d,
        max(d) OVER (rows BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND current row) AS max_so_far
    FROM ( 
      -- sorted ON c 
      SELECT 
        a,
        b,
        c,
        d
      FROM dataset.table
      ORDER BY  c 
    ) 
 )
```